# invalid value specified for function parameter. Function Name:DatePart

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have to create a landing page that allows the modification of an existing record and for that, I have to generate the information about the records so he can update it. I already finished the page with HTML and JS and when I add the AMPScript code I'm getting the following error message:

> **Invalid value specified for function parameter.**
> **Function Name:** DatePart
> **Parameter Name:** Date
> **Parameter Ordinal:** 1
> **Parameter Type:** Date
> **Submitted Value:** System.Data.DataRow
> **ClientID:** 7221705
> **JobID:** 0
> **ListID:** 15425
> **BatchID:** 0
> **SubcriberID:** 327073156
> **Data Source Type:** List

**This is my AMP Script code:**

```
%%[
  /* Set Variables here for easy editing */ 
  SET @uid = AttributeValue("UID_TARGET")
  SET @rows  = LookupRows("ENT.CUSTOMER_LOT_6", "UID_TARGET", @uid)
  SET @count = RowCount(@rows)
  IF (@count == 1) THEN
    SET  @row = row(@rows,1)
    SET @sexe = Uppercase(field(@row,"GENDER"))
    SET @firstname = field(@row,"FIRSTNAME")
    SET @lastname = field(@row,"SURNAME") 
    SET @email = field(@row,"EMAIL")
    SET @tel = field(@row,"PHONENUMBER")
    SET @date = field(@date,"BIRTHDATE")
    /*  SET @langue = field(@row,"PREFERRED_LANGUAGE" */
    SET @year = DatePart(@date,"Y")
    SET @month = DatePart(@date,"M")
    SET @day = DatePart(@date,"D")    
    IF EMPTY(@date) AND ISNULL(@date) THEN
      SET @Date=""    
    ELSE
      SET @Date=CONCAT(@day,"/",@month,"/",@year)                 
    ENDIF                   
  ENDIF
]%%
```

Answer (score 3):

You made a mistake when reading the date-value into your variable, as you used the data-variable for the first parameter which should be the row to read from.

Instead of `SET @date = field(@date,"BIRTHDATE")` you need to use `SET @date = field(@row,"BIRTHDATE")`

Furthermore I think you might want to change the following if-statement from `IF EMPTY(@date) AND ISNULL(@date) THEN` to `IF EMPTY(@date) THEN` as the empty-function returns true if the variable is an empty string or null and therefore your current if-statement would only be true if date is null and changing to "OR" would lead to the same result as omitting `ISNULL(@date)`.

**Complete code:**

```
%%[
  Var @uid, @rows, @count, @row, @sexe, @firstname, @lastname, @email, @tel, @date, @DateString, @year, @month, @day
  /* Set Variables here for easy editing */ 
  SET @uid = AttributeValue("UID_TARGET")
  SET @rows  = LookupRows("ENT.CUSTOMER_LOT_6", "UID_TARGET", @uid)
  SET @count = RowCount(@rows)
  IF (@count == 1) THEN
    SET  @row = row(@rows,1)
    SET @sexe = Uppercase(field(@row,"GENDER"))
    SET @firstname = field(@row,"FIRSTNAME")
    SET @lastname = field(@row,"SURNAME") 
    SET @email = field(@row,"EMAIL")
    SET @tel = field(@row,"PHONENUMBER")
    SET @date = field(@row,"BIRTHDATE",0)
    /*  SET @langue = field(@row,"PREFERRED_LANGUAGE") */   
    IF EMPTY(@date) THEN
      SET @DateString=""
    ELSE
      SET @year = DatePart(@date,"Y")
      SET @month = DatePart(@date,"M")
      SET @day = DatePart(@date,"D") 
      SET @DateString=CONCAT(@day,"/",@month,"/",@year)                 
    ENDIF                   
  ENDIF
]%%
```

**Related documentation:**

- [Field(1,2,3)](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/field/)
- [Empty(1)](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/empty/)

Comment: thank you Markus for your update
but i still have the same error message: **Invalid value specified for function parameter. Function Name: DatePart Parameter Name: Date Parameter Ordinal: 1 Parameter Type: Date Submitted Value: System.Data.DataRow ClientID: 7221705 JobID: 0 ListID: 15425 BatchID: 0 SubcriberID: 327073156 Data Source Type: List**

Comment: Another thing I can think of is that there is a problem with having one `@date` and another `@Date` variable, maybe rename one of them (I did this in my answer). From the error message it seems like you are passing a variable containing a date to the Field-function, which should be fixed in the code presented in my answer. Furthermore I moved construction of the dateparts into the else as it can only be done if date is set.